# Wrong conditional status calculated

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following query:

```
select rep_id, r.onboarded_at, user_id, u.created_at, pi.applied_at,
    case when count(user_id) over (partition by rep_id order by convert_timezone('PST', pi.applied_at) rows unbounded preceding) >= 5 then 'x'
         when count(user_id) over (partition by rep_id order by convert_timezone('PST', pi.applied_at) rows unbounded preceding) >= 3 then 'y'
         when count(user_id) over (partition by rep_id order by convert_timezone('PST', pi.applied_at) rows unbounded preceding) >= 1 then 'z'
         else null
         end status
    FROM users u
    left OUTER JOIN reps r on r.id=u.advisor_id
    left outer join info pi on r.id = pi.g_id
```

Current (undesired) output:

```
rep_id  onboarded_at    user_id created_at  applied_at  status
180     12/7/2016       2999    6/7/2017    6/7/2017    x
180     12/7/2016       4223    7/30/2017   8/11/2017   x
180     12/7/2016       25064   12/14/2017  12/25/2017  y
180     12/7/2016       33046   1/5/2018    (null)      z
180     12/7/2016       33818   1/8/2018    (null)      z
180     12/7/2016       43814   3/22/2018   3/28/2018   y
180     12/7/2016       43978   3/23/2018   (null)      z
180     12/7/2016       43445   3/27/2018   3/29/2018   z
180     12/7/2016       43567   3/30/2018   (null)      z
```

Expected output:

```
rep_id  onboarded_at    user_id created_at  applied_at  status
180     12/7/2016       2999    6/7/2017    6/7/2017    x
180     12/7/2016       4223    7/30/2017   8/11/2017   x
180     12/7/2016       25064   12/14/2017  12/25/2017  y
180     12/7/2016       33046   1/5/2018    (null)      **y**
180     12/7/2016       33818   1/8/2018    (null)      **y**
180     12/7/2016       43814   3/22/2018   3/28/2018   y
180     12/7/2016       43978   3/23/2018   (null)      **y**
180     12/7/2016       43445   3/27/2018   3/29/2018   z
180     12/7/2016       43567   3/30/2018   (null)      z
```

Basically, whenever applied_at is null: it gets an automatic status='z' for some reason, but the status of the previous record should just carry over to the next; only next non-null applied_at can change the status (if it passes the respective threshold of >=1, >=3, >=5).

Any ideas how to correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to order by `created_at` rather than `applied_at` or perhaps a combination of both:

```
select rep_id, r.onboarded_at, user_id, u.created_at, pi.applied_at,
       (case when count(user_id) over (partition by rep_id order by convert_timezone('PST', coalesce(pi.applied_at, pi.created_id)) rows unbounded preceding) >= 5 then 'x'
             when count(user_id) over (partition by rep_id order by convert_timezone('PST', coalesce(pi.applied_at, pi.created_id)) rows unbounded preceding) >= 3 then 'y'
             when count(user_id) over (partition by rep_id order by convert_timezone('PST', coalesce(pi.applied_at, pi.created_id)) nulls unbounded preceding) >= 1 then 'z'
             else null
        end) status
from users u left join
     reps r
     on r.id = u.advisor_id left join
     info pi
     on r.id = pi.g_id;
```

Comment: this doesn't work. created_at is a field I need, but it should not be considered as part of the status calculation. I realized this can be solved by `count(applied_at) over (partition by r.id order by convert_timezone('PST', pi.applied_at) rows unbounded preceding) >=...` but can you suggest how can I change my current query to satisfy the desired output?